# Fortran like Modules in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, module, fortran, c++14

I read the other day that the next standard of C++ will have modules which can be used like the well known Fortran modules (.mod extension).

A C++11 was foreseeing it, and I think it referred to the C++14 standard, but if it will be in the standard was still uncertain.

For what I heard we will have to wait until the next maybe C++17 standard.

Now since we have object files, headers and libraries if we wish, I still do not understand what is so different about modules.

Creating a module in Fortran will hide the definitions for the user which in a header usually can be seen by the user, of course as forward declaration. I see it more as an disadvantage for people who want to use that feature.

So what are really the advantages of modules? Should we use that instead as soon when it's supported?

Comment: Obligatory: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ND-TuW0KIgg

Comment: Okay, yeah it's the same question from a different focus. Thanks! About that video ... hmm... funny.